# Remove XML declaration while passing XML into a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I need to remove XML Declaration while passing XML into a Stored Procedure
Because if we include the XML declaration it will give an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHIFT-JIS" standalone="yes"?>
```

I googled a lot but still cannot solve my above issue. Please help!

```
(0x80131904) XML line 1 character 9 . cannot be switch ...
```

Comment: What language are you executing the stored procedure with? SQL? C#?

Comment: SQL server and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that, it works for me:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlfilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT_JIS"));
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(xml); 
                    if (doc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                        doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
                    xml = GetXMLAsString(doc);


 public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
        {

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            myxml.WriteTo(tx);

            string str = sw.ToString();// 
            return str;
        }
```